# Unix timestamp in telegraf config

Tags: apache-kafka, timestamp, influxdb, telegraf

my issue has to do with the timestamp format that has to be used between telegraf and kafka.
I send some data from kafka to telegraf with the intention to insert them into the Influx database, and the timestamp in that data is in unix timestamp format. 

An example of the format of the data is:

> "ticks,market_id=12345 c=120.961,bid=120.946,ask=120.976,market_type=3i 1571761012.466296"

So I get the error:

> E! [inputs.kafka_consumer] Error in plugin: metric parse error: expected timestamp at 1:82: "ticks,market_id=12345 c=120.961,bid=120.946,ask=120.976,market_type=3i 1571761012.466296"

the last part is obviously the timestamp (already converted in utc time). 
My telegraf input configuration is :

```py
 ## Data format to consume.
  ## Each data format has its own unique set of configuration options, read
  ## more about them here:
  ## https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md
  data_format = "influx"
```

if my format was csv I would add the

> csv_timestamp_format = "unix"

and the timestamp would be recognised as a unix one without an issue , but I cannot find something similar for the influx configuration.

I read in the Influx documentation that

> Timestamps must be in Unix time and are assumed to be in nanoseconds. A different precision can be provided, see the HTTP syntax for details.

so in the case that nothing more is needed , what is wrong with my data , maybe something in the syntax? 
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you need to delete the `.`:

`1571761012.466296 -> 1571761012466296`